# GAE, This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application

Tags: google-app-engine

I use `GAE` standard environment and `cron service`. I deploy my app and cron jobs successfully based on `app.yaml` and `cron.yaml`.

And, when I run cron jobs firstly. I got below logs from `stackdriver`:

> This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.
>
> A problem was encountered with the process that handled this request, causing it to exit. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application.

How do I solve this? thanks.

Comment: Check your request and, if available, your app logs in Stackdriver. Depending on the exact environment and language you use they may contain information critical for identifying the problem. For example standard env python 2.7 logs would typically contain the traceback for the app failure. Without such info it's practically impossible to tell what's going on.